# Is there a nice visualization of the length of a curve formula?

Tags: real-analysis, curves, visualization, arc-length

We know that if there is a curve $$\Gamma=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\ :\ y=f(x), x\in[a,b]\}$$ then 
$$\text{length}(\Gamma)=\int\limits_a^b\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}dt$$ 
and I get that this is because 
$$\text{length}(\Gamma)=\int\limits_\Gamma1=\int\limits_a^b1\cdot|\gamma'(t)|dt=\int\limits_a^b|(\gamma_1'(t),\gamma_2'(t))|dt=\int\limits_a^b\sqrt{\gamma_1'(t)^2+\gamma_2'(t)^2}dt$$ where $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))=(t,f(t))$

But $\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}$ is another function in itself and I would like to see what it corresponds to, is there a way of comparing the two functions in a more meaningful way then just the reasoning that I wrote above?

I am looking for an animation or a drawing or simply an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula arises from an analysis of the curve $(t,f(t))$. Suppose you move from
a point $p_1=(t_1,f(t_1))$ to a point $p_2(t_2,f(t_2))$ on the curve, with $t_1<t_2$. If $t_1,t_2$ are sufficiently close to each other, the distance between these two points is close to the length of the piece of the curve between the points $p_1,p_2$. Now the distance is simply:
$$d(p_1,p_2)=\sqrt{(t_2-t_1)^2+(f(t_2)-f(t_1))^2}$$
Assuming $f$ is differentiable, the mean value theorem guarantees that we can find a point $\xi\in(t_1,t_2)$ such that
$$f(t_2)-f(t_1)=f'(\xi)(t_2-t_1)$$
so we can write
$$d(p_1,p_2)=\sqrt{(t_1-t_2)^2+(f^{'}(\xi))^2(t_2-t_1)^2}=(t_2-t_1)\sqrt{1+(f'(\xi))^2}$$
Now if we partition the curve into points $(t_1,f(t_1)),(t_2,f(t_2)),\dots,(t_n,f(t_n))$ and add all these distances we just calculated, we obtain the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(t_{i+1}-t_i)\sqrt{(f'(\xi_i))^2+1}$$
which is a Riemman sum for the integral $\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ then $\gamma'(t)=(x'(t),y'(t))$ and $\gamma'(t)dt = (dx,dy)$, so the infinitesimal element of length is $\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} = \|\gamma'(t)\|\,dt$ and $\|\gamma'(t)\|=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}$. If $\gamma$ is the graph of a function we have $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=f(t)$, so $\|\gamma'(t)\|=\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$. Long story short, they are *exactly* the same formula.

Comment: Hmm yes, but isn't this kind the same as what I wrote?

Comment: @JohnCataldo: you wrote *[...] is another function in itself* and I am pointing out that no, it is not a different function. It is just the same object. The element of length is the same, despite the chosen coordinates. Of course its representation changes accordingly.

Comment: I mean it's a pretty different function from $f$, I was interested in the relationship between $f$ and the function whose integral gives the length of the graph of $f$ (in a visual way)

Comment: @JohnCataldo: and what else do you expect besides the definition $g(t)=\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}$? A comparison between the $L^2$ norms, leading to the isoperimetric inequality?

Comment: No you know perhaps like an animation the takes the graph of $f$, stretches is it in some way... Not sure what I was looking for exactly

Comment: @JohnCataldo: oh, all right. Then we have that $g(t)\approx 1$ in the regions where the derivative of $f$ is small (i.e. $f$ is slowly increasing/decreasing), and $g(t)\approx \left|f'(t)\right|=|\tan\theta|$ in the regions where $f(t)$ is rapidly increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

I did not feel like drawing so I'm just going to write.

Imagine the graph of a function, and on it two points $f(x)$ and $f(x+\Delta x)$. Sketch lines through these points that are parallel to the axes - this will form two right triangles which are essentially the same.

On both of these triangles, one of the legs has length $\Delta x$, and the other $\vert f(x)-f(x+\Delta x) \vert.$ By Pythagoras, the hypothenuse therefore has length
$$\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (f(x)-f(x+\Delta x))^2}.$$
The hypothenuse is a good approximation of the length of the curve generated by $f$ between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$.

Now,
$$\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (f(x)-f(x+\Delta x))^2} = \Delta x \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{f(x)-f(x+\Delta x)}{\Delta x}\right)^2},$$
which becomes
$$ \sqrt{1+(f')^2}\;dx $$
when you let $\Delta x \to 0$.
So you can think of this function as an infinitesimal length of the curve $f$ gives rise to.